# How do we send a array in x-www-form-urlencoded in react-native

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, react-native, x-www-form-urlencoded

this is function for sending the API

```
export const socialPostMurmur= (publicKey,content,sig,visibility,video,photo)=>{
  // console.log(publicKey,content,sig,visibility,video,photo);

  console.log('photo',photo);

let data;

  data="pub=" + publicKey.toString() +
  "&content=" + content +
  "&sig=" + sig.sig +
  "&visibility=" + visibility +
  "&videos=[]" +
  "&photos=" + photo

  console.log("data====",data)


  fetch('https://murmurjapi.wandx.co/accounts/postMurmur', {
method: 'POST',
headers: new Headers({
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
  Accept: "application/json"
}),
body:data
}).then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  console.log("New post is called",responseJson);
  // return responseJson.movies;
})
.catch((error) => {
console.error('this is error',error);
});
}
```

here photo and video in argument of function is array.
So when im doing console.log('photo',photo); im getting proper array like this:

```
["QmYTLjw3dzwNVzhMZGVdbZwbt7KTfc51exCWXeTKsy2bff-image-jpg-general"]
```

but when im sending data to API and printing it.its not showing it like an array, and in response to api call im getting status failed err null.

**this how array is printing in API:**

**photos=QmYTLjw3dzwNVzhMZGVdbZwbt7KTfc51exCWXeTKsy2bff-image-jpg-general**

this is my data which is going in API

console.log("data====",data)

```
pub=EOS7qoTnhdcdihvcvEBkqNJ21iNwFJURRvgciHCuG2ihsvPZyPdL4&content=H&sig=SIG_K1_JwaNudk7P6AeogY9LSKey7hTwSTYM9E1GsLF3twRgqap6zCFVY78PzZgF1yA6GUTdDuC4vNXo1vUgwFCFKHppsyHc1zGVb&visibility=1&videos=[]&photos=QmYTLjw3dzwNVzhMZGVdbZwbt7KTfc51exCWXeTKsy2bff-image-jpg-general
```

this is response im getting after API call

```
New post is called 
{status: false, err: {…}}
status: false
err: {}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Send your data as JSON Object. i think your API is not expecting formData.

Answer (score 0):

There's no *standard* way to encode an array in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. A common extension (which is supported by PHP (natively) and [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) (in extended mode)) is to suffix the name with `[]` and repeat it for each value in the array.

i.e.

```js
const animals = ["dog", "cat", "mouse"];
const field_name = "animal[]";
const url_encoded_animals = animals.map(
    value =>
        `${encodeURIComponent(field_name)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`
);
const form_encoded = url_encoded_animals.join("&");
console.log(form_encoded);
```